# How to Assert Dictionaries in Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections, dictionary

Do you know how I can Assert two dictionaries of type

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>>
```

in my Unit test project?

I tried with CollectionsAssert but it didn' work for me.I guess that it takes to simple Dictionaries as parameters(e.g. `Dictionary<string,string>`).I guess that the problem for me comes from the second parameter of the dictionary.Do you know how I can assert those two dictionaries?

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the ways that would give you a good error message:

```
public string ToAssertableString(IDictionary<string,List<string>> dictionary) {
    var pairStrings = dictionary.OrderBy(p => p.Key)
                                .Select(p => p.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", p.Value));
    return string.Join("; ", pairStrings);
}

// ...
Assert.AreEqual(ToAssertableString(dictionary1), ToAssertableString(dictionary2));
```

Comment: what if dictionary holds list of objects as values ?

Answer (score 11):

using Linq:

```
Dictionary.All(e => AnotherDictionary.Contains(e))
```

Comment: Nice...Just need to make sure to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: This works for C# 3.0 and above.  For C# 2.0 one can use:  `delegate(KeyValuePair<string, string> e) { return properties.Contains(e); }`

Comment: That just checks AnotherDictionary is a superset of Dictionary. Not that they are equal.

Comment: Checking the Count of both dictionaries would solve this subset issue.